# Получить заголовки из запроса на сервер Flask

Tags: python, flask, requests

Есть небольшой сервер на Фласке. Нужно проверить заголовки запроса и в одном случае вернуть код ответа 200, в другом 500
На текущий момент код выглядит так

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return "<h3>Main Page</h3>"

@app.route("/response")
def response():
    if condition == ___:
        res = make_response("<h3>Success</h3>", 200)
        res.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/html'
    else:
        res = make_response("<h3>Error</h3>", 500)
        res.headers['Content-type'] = 'text/html'
    return res

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Соответственно вопрос в том как получить эти самые заголовки

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Получить заголовки можно через [объект запроса](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.request).

***Пример:***

```py
from flask import request
...

@app.route("/response")
def response():
    request.headers
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]